# Block not showing up

Tags: blocks

I am building a fairly simple module, and I am trying to set up a block, but it doesn't appear. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
function quick_links_block_info() {
  $blocks['quick_links_staff'] = array(
    'info' => t('Quick Links'),
    'status' => 1,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function quick_links_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quick_links_staff':
      $block['subject'] = t('Quick Links');
      $block['content'] = quick_links_get_links();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}


function quick_links_get_links($department = '') {
  return t('Hi');
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us more information on what you've done thus far. Did you flush your cache? and make sure that you've enabled your module? have you tried using the examples module found here: http://drupalcode.org/project/examples.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/block_example/block_example.module?

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of the block hooks is wrong.  Try the below:

```
function quick_links_block_info() {
  $blocks['quick_links_staff'] = array(
    'info' => t('Quick Links'),
    'status' => 1,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function quick_links_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quick_links_staff':
      $block['subject'] = t('Quick Links');
      $block['content'] = quick_links_get_links();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}


function quick_links_get_links($department = '') {
  return t('Hi');
}
```

I've namespaced the block, and changed the status from TRUE to 1, as per the `hook_block_info()` docs.  I've also removed the assignment of `$delta`, as this is passed through automatically.

**REFERENCES**

[`hook_block_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)

[`hook_block_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

Comment: Thanks Chapa, I did figure out that I had to make the above changes but am still not seeing the block. I know the code is being reached, because I can output other things. Just not the block..

Comment: Did you assign the block to a region on the currently used theme?

Comment: This is the correct answer: If you define the block as `$blocks['quick_links']`, and then return its content when `$delta` is equal to `'staff'`, the block is not rendered.

Comment: Hi kiamlaluno, thanks for pointing it out. i did notice that I had to provide the same index used in $blocks to the $delta that and I fixed the code, but the block never showed up even after the fix. so i'm still confused/baffled

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I cleared all caches under performance and my module showed up in blocks.

Comment: In this case, the problem is not the cache. The code used from the OP defines a block with an ID, and then outputs the block content when the block ID is another one.

Comment: Thats not the case at all! i fixed my code moments after posting it, and it still does not work. till this day..

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
'status' => 0
```

or

```
'status' => 1,
```

and provide a region like this:

```
'status' => 1,
'region' => 'footer',
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the Module and install the module again and you will be able to see the block that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- double check your module is loaded properly and there are no typos,
- you're testing it on the right environment:),
- clear all caches (including `memcached`/`redis`) either in *Performance* or by `drush cc all`,
- disable 'Cache blocks' (and other caches) in *Performance*
- restart Apache server (it could be `OPCache`/`XCache`),
- check if Apache user has read access to your module file or folder,
- check logs (e.g. `drush watchdog-show --tail`),
- install `drush_extras` and run: `drush block-show` to see if your block is on the list
- see if the block is loadable either at `/devel/php` or via `drush`:

  ```
  drush ev "var_dump(block_load('foomodule', 'foodelta'));"
  ```