# Module Block does not show up

Tags: 7, blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Block not showing up in drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50704/block-not-showing-up-in-drupal)

For some odd reason, This very simple module block does not show up in structure 
under the list of viable blocks. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
[quick_links.info]

name= Quick Links
description = Simple block with links
package = Mpackage
core = 7.x
files[] = quick_links.module



[quick_links.module]

function quick_links_block_info() {
  $blocks['quick_links_staff'] = array(
    'info' => t('Quick Link'),
    'status' => 1,
  );
  return $blocks;
}//TODO add caching option

function quick_links_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'quick_links_staff' :
      $block['subject'] = t('Quick Link');
      $block['content'] = t('links go here');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real explanation why my solution worked; I only replaced quick_links_staff with quick_links in both places.

```
function quick_links_block_info() {
  $blocks['quick_links'] = array(
    'info' => t('Quick Link'),
    'status' => 1,
  );
  return $blocks;
}//TODO add caching option

function quick_links_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
  case 'quick_links':
    $block['subject'] = t('Quick Link');
    $block['content'] = t('links go here');
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Make sure to clear Drupal cache after you implement the change.

Comment: The code shown from the OP should work; changing the block delta is not what should make the difference. Probably, the OP didn't clear the cache, and edited an already enabled module.

Comment: I agree with you @kiamlaluno, but before I posted my answer I tried use the same block delta "quick_links_staff" and cleared Drupal cache using drush and I also, disabled the module and enabled it again after the first enable. have you tried it?

Comment: Drupal doesn't have restrictions for the values `$delta` can assume. Using quick_links_staff, or quick_links doesn't make any difference, for Drupal. If quick_links works, but quick_links_staff doesn't, the reason is another one.

Comment: I have updated my code and cleared the cache a million times. I can create a block in any other module, but this one is still not working. I can see the module in my list of modules, but no block shows up when the module is enabled. I'm quite confused at this point ~:-(